# How to receive JSON POST data from asp.net to php?

Tags: php, asp.net, json, rest, api

I am trying to build an API for my php website and the API is using from asp.net site to insert data to my php MySql site. I have checked this with the postman and it is working. But while accessing from asp.net it is just getting the null values only. The data posted from using JSON from asp.net is

***JSON*** **POST** array from **asp.net**

```
    string reqJson = "{\"user_id\":\"" + user_id + "\",\"name\":\"" + name + "\",\"branch\": " + branch + "," + " \"agency\" : \"" + agency + "\"}";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqJson);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip");


                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var rsp = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                if (rsp == null)
                {

                }
                using (System.IO.StreamReader rdstrm = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseString = rdstrm.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                }
```

This is the requested JSON

```
{"AllowAutoRedirect":true,"AllowWriteStreamBuffering":true,"AllowReadStreamBuffering":false,"HaveResponse":false,"KeepAlive":true,"Pipelined":true,"PreAuthenticate":false,"UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing":false,"SendChunked":false,"AutomaticDecompression":0,"MaximumResponseHeadersLength":64,"ClientCertificates":[],"CookieContainer":null,"SupportsCookieContainer":true,"RequestUri":"http://localhost:9080/api/ucd.php","ContentLength":81,"Timeout":100000,"ReadWriteTimeout":300000,"ContinueTimeout":350,"Address":"http://localhost:9080/api/ucd.php","ContinueDelegate":null,"ServicePoint":{"BindIPEndPointDelegate":null,"ConnectionLeaseTimeout":-1,"Address":"http://localhost:9080/api/ucd.php","MaxIdleTime":100000,"UseNagleAlgorithm":true,"ReceiveBufferSize":-1,"Expect100Continue":true,"IdleSince":"\/Date(1542637743629)\/","ProtocolVersion":{"Major":1,"Minor":1,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"ConnectionName":"http","ConnectionLimit":2147483647,"CurrentConnections":0,"Certificate":null,"ClientCertificate":null,"SupportsPipelining":true},"Host":"localhost","MaximumAutomaticRedirections":50,"Method":"POST","Credentials":null,"UseDefaultCredentials":false,"ConnectionGroupName":null,"Headers":["Content-Type","Accept","Accept-Encoding"],"Proxy":{"Credentials":null},"ProtocolVersion":{"Major":1,"Minor":1,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1},"ContentType":"application/json","MediaType":null,"TransferEncoding":null,"Connection":null,"Accept":"application/json","Referer":null,"UserAgent":null,"Expect":null,"IfModifiedSince":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Date":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ServerCertificateValidationCallback":null,"CreatorInstance":{},"CachePolicy":{"Level":1},"AuthenticationLevel":1,"ImpersonationLevel":4}
```

the above is autogenerated while posting JSON request

The *receiving* **PHP** code is

```
 <?php

include_once('config.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){


//Posting the data here
$user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$user_name= $_POST['name'];
$branch= $_POST['branch'];
$agency= $_POST['agency'];



//This below method also tried but the same showing.
/*$portal = isset($_POST['portal']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['portal']) : "";
$pax_name = isset($_POST['pax_name']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pax_name']) : "";
$ticket_no = isset($_POST['ticket_no']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ticket_no']) : "";
$adtorch = isset($_POST['adtorch']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['adtorch']) : "";
$airline_code = isset($_POST['airline_code']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['airline_code']) : "";*/


 // Insert data into data base
 $sql = "INSERT INTO portal_users (pu_user_id, pu_username, pu_branch, pu_agency) VALUES ('" .$user_id."','".$user_name."','".$branch."','".$agency."');";
 $qur = $conn->query($sql);
 if($qur){
 $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => $user_id);
 }else{
 $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
 }
}else{
 $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}

mysqli_close($conn);

/* Output header */
 header('Content-type:  application/json');
 echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

is there any issue at posted value receiving? It's a json request. so I want to use the decode method? I am a beginner, so i don't know to decode.

I  have tried this method also

```
$r_val = file_get_contents("php://input");
$r_data = json_decode($r_val, true);


$user_id= $r_data ['user_id'];
$user_name= $r_data ['name'];
$branch= $r_data ['branch'];
$agency= $r_data ['agency'];
```

Comment: Have you set Origin headers on the  .net webapi ?

Comment: Anyone knows how to sort it out?

Comment: answer the question

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier Origin headers? You mean these..?  request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip");

Comment: Why are you sending the data as json, while you use $_POST, what uses a different encoding system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO receive json POST data in php we should use below code

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); //This will post JSON into $postdata as a JSON string
$postdataArray = json_decode($postdata, true); //This will convert JSON string into array
```

In your case replace below code

```
//Posting the data here
$user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$user_name= $_POST['name'];
$branch= $_POST['branch'];
$agency= $_POST['agency'];
```

With this code

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$postdataArray = json_decode($postdata, true);
$user_id= $postdataArray['user_id'];
$user_name= $postdataArray['name'];
$branch= $postdataArray['branch'];
$agency= $postdataArray['agency'];
```

Comment: Pitidar :   I have tried this method, then it is showing unexpected error.

Comment: can you paste the error message? You are posting it from asp.net to the PHP page, right?

Comment: this is the error message that i am getting. Unexpected ''

Comment: Do two things 
1. Remove  ; from below line
`$sql = "INSERT INTO portal_users (pu_user_id, pu_username, pu_branch, pu_agency) VALUES ('" .$user_id."','".$user_name."','".$branch."','".$agency."');";`

Update Code

`$sql = "INSERT INTO portal_users (pu_user_id, pu_username, pu_branch, pu_agency) VALUES ('" .$user_id."','".$user_name."','".$branch."','".$agency."')";`

2. For debugging remove all the other code and just print $postdataArray and check

Comment: from which line??

Comment: It's not getting print while checking without other codes. so the posted value is not getting captured

Comment: Yes, that means your asp.net code is not posting data to php file, try to debug on asp.net code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183944/discussion-between-kishor-patidar-and-rashid).

Answer (score 1):

you need to receive the json value like this -

```
$r_val = file_get_contents("php://input");
$r_data = json_decode($r_val, true);
```

here $r_data is an array. you will get your expected value in this array like below-

```
$user_id= $r_data ['user_id'];
$user_name= $r_data ['name'];
$branch= $r_data ['branch'];
$agency= $r_data ['agency'];
```

Comment: while doing like this, it's showing an error as unexpected

Comment: it is coming from asp.net

Comment: the code seems okay. you should debug it line by line to find out exactly for which line you are getting unexpected error

Comment: actually the posted data is not getting posted on the page